# How do I match 0,2,3,4 elements of one array to 0,2,3,4 elements of another array and print the 5th element from both the arrays in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to match the 0,2,3,4 elements of an array storing the columns of one tab delimited file to 0,2,3,4 elements of another array storing the columns of another tab delimited file and print out the element 5 (column 6) from both the input files in python.

Here is the code that I worked on but I guess that the code matches line by line between two files. However, I wanted to match the line of  file1 to any line in file 2

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import itertools
import csv, pprint
from array import *
#print len(sys.argv)
if len(sys.argv) != 4:
print 'Usage: python scores.py <infile1> <infile2> <outfile>'
sys.exit(1)

f1=open("/home/user/ab/ab/ab/file1.txt", "r")
f2 = open ("/home/user/ab/ab/ab/file2.txt", "r")
f3 = open ("out.txt", "w")

lines1 = f1.readlines()
lines2 = f2.readlines()

for f1line, f2line in zip(lines1, lines2): ## for loop to read lines line by line simultaneously from two files
    #for f1line, f2line in itertools.izip(lines1,lines2):
    row1 = f1line.split('\t') #split on tab
    row2 = f2line.split('\t') # split on tab

    if ((row1[0:1] + row1[2:5]) == (row2[0:1] + row2[2:5])): # columns 0,2,3,4 matching between two infiles 
        writer = csv.writer(f3, delimiter = '\t')
        writer.writerow((row1[0:1] + row1[2:5]) + row1[5:6] + (row2[0:1] + row2[2:5]) + row2[5:6])
```

Comment: Does this code not work?  If so, what output do you get?

Comment: This code works but I get only 984 lines which is less..as the two input files are supposed to be same, so the output should have more lines of matches

Comment: In this code, it reads line 1 of file 1 , matches with line 2 of file 2 and so on. However, I want to match line1 of file1 anywhere in the file2

Answer (score 2):

For each line on file 1 to match

```
op = operator.itemgetter(0,2,3,4)
f2 = file2.readlines() # otherwise it won't work every loop

for line1 in file1:
    ... #split 1
    for line2 in f2:
        ... #split 2
        if op(row1) == op(row2):
            ...
```

Answer (score 1):

So, just do what you said: for each line of file1, match each line of file2

```
for f1line in lines1:
    row1 = f1line.split('\t') #split on tab
    for f2line in lines2:
        row2 = f2line.split('\t') # split on tab
        if ((row1[0:1] + row1[2:5]) == (row2[0:1] + row2[2:5])):
            ...
```

Comment: `for f1line in lines1, lines2:` this loop will iterate 2 times, the first time the value of f1line will be lines1, the next time, it will be lines2.

Comment: This nested for loop just gives me the  last line of both the files

Comment: @user1389479 i don't see any problem with the loops, can you print out each `row1` and `row2`, and check what you get?

Comment: or is there any way in python to read each line of first file and compare with all the lines of second file insted of zip function here that matches line by line? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that each key value (row[0,3,4,5]) is unique per file:

```
import sys
import csv

datalen = 12
keyfn  = lambda row: tuple(row[0:1] + row[3:6])
datafn = lambda row: row[8:datalen]

def load_dict(fname, keyfn, datafn):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as inf:
        data = (row.split() for row in inf if not row.startswith('##'))
        return {keyfn(row):datafn(row) for row in data if len(row) >= datalen}

def main(fname1, fname2, outfname):
    data1 = load_dict(fname1, keyfn, datafn)
    data2 = load_dict(fname2, keyfn, datafn)

    common_keys = sorted(set(data1).intersection(data2))
    with open(outfname, 'wb') as outf:
        outcsv = csv.writer(outf, delimiter='\t')
        outcsv.writerows(list(key) + data1[key] + data2[key] for key in common_keys)

if __name__=="__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print 'Usage: python scores.py <infile1> <infile2> <outfile>'
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        main(*sys.argv[1:4])
```

**Edit:** problems found:

I made one mistake: the return value from the key function was a list; a list is not hashable, therefore cannot be a dictionary key. I have made the return value a tuple instead.

You, on the other hand, failed to mention that

- your files begin with several lines of comments (I have modified the script to ignore comment rows, meaning anything starting with `##`)
- your file is NOT tab-delimited (or at least the file examples you provided are not). It actually seems to be columnar, separated with multiple spaces - this cannot be handled by the csv module. Luckily, the data seems simple enough to use .split() instead.
- you are matching on the wrong columns; column 2 in your data files does not appear to match between files at all. I think you need to key on columns 0, 3, 4, 5 instead. I have updated keyfn to reflect this.

Columns 3 and 4 appear to be identical, but I am not certain of this. If columns 3 and 4 are always identical, you could save some memory and speed things up a bit by only keying on columns 0, 4, 5: `keyfn  = lambda row: tuple(row[0:1] + row[4:6])`

I am guessing that columns 8,9,10,11 are the desired data; I have changed datafn to reflect this. The script should now work as required.

Comment: i am getting error for this line of code                             return {keyfn(row):datafn(row) for row in incsv}

Comment: The error is specifically this one                                    File "qual1.py", line 25
    return  {keyfn(row):datafn(row) for row in incsv}
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @user1389479: if you are using a version of Python prior to 2.7, you may need to replace that line with `return dict([(keyfn(row),datafn(row)) for row in incsv])`

Comment: Thanks..the error is not shown up but the output file it generates is empty.

Comment: @user1389479: could you send me, say, the first ten lines of each input file? hugh_bothwell at hotmail dot com - I'll see if I can figure out what's failing.

Comment: hey, the file is tab delimited, and the 0,2,3,4 elements , i said was array elements not the file columns , file columns that I want to match would be 1,3,4,5 and print the columns 6 from both the input files to output

Comment: @user1389479: the files you sent had no tabs in them - none, zero, nada. Does your text editor automatically replace tabs with spaces? Anyway, .split() will work for tabs too. The first data row in infile1 looks like `['1','CGI','SNV','753845','753846','197','+','.','ID=5;Reference_seq=T;Variant_seq=G;Genotype=homozygous','TAT','G','ATC']` and in infile2 `['1','VCF','deletion','753845','753846','197','+','.','ID=41;Reference_seq=CCT;Variant_seq=C;Genotype=heterozygous','GCC','C','TGA']` - counting from column 0, infile2 column 2 contains `deletion` which does not match any infile1 column.

Comment: It is giving me the error in the return statement..i dont know why File "qual2.py", line 18
    return {keyfn(row):datafn(row) for row in incsv if len(row) >= datalen}
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax